# I cant figure out why photoshop sometimes shifts my pixel grid when I change image size to 200% and 50% for retina

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

My flow has always been to start at 1X and use image>image size>200% to get 2x and I flip between the 2 using 50% to get back to 1x.

But for no apparent reason, 1 out of 50-ish times it shifts everything off of my pixel grid into sub pixels.

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Why would you not start at 200% and downsize? Unless you're exporting vectors, you will be losing quality. What do you mean by "into sub pixels"?

Comment: I'm using vectors and smart objects for images. Starting at 1X is the best way to ensure your work stays on the pixel grid. If you want to start at 2x, you will have to make sure all of your objects and their locations can be divided by 2. If not your elements will be in between pixels(sub pixels), which renders them and blurry. example: a box that is 5x5 divided by 2 for non retina ends up being 2.5x2.5 which isn't sharp.